# Is it OK to manually create a directory inside node_module?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Is it OK to manually create a directory inside `node_module` and place some modules there?
For example I may want to create a directory named `models` inside `node_modules` and place my models there, so I can do

```
var Person = require("models/person");
```

I know it works fine, but is it considered a bad practice if I do so?

Comment: is there any reason not to make person a proper npm module? I does not have to live in main npmjs registry - you can install from git (including private github repo)

Comment: @AndreySidorov, that sounds like a good idea. Although I am still eager to know the answer to my original question (I am just curious).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While of course you could put your code anywhere you'd like in your project, here are the few reasons I do not put application code in that folder:

1. I exclude that folder from the Git source repository normally (as the contents can be recreated)
2. I treat the `node_modules` folder as read-only third party references that are outside of my control and sourced elsewhere, and something that I can recreate easily assuming the NPM repository is available at the time.
3. I'd rather have a top level folder called `models` as in your example instead of it being buried in amongst code I did not write.
4. The `models` folder doesn't conflict with anything else in the top level folder.

Th only exception would be shared private packages ... But as they are shared I wouldn't consider them as code that I would edit as part of the application. And they would be installed as part of NPM process.

As an example the project I'm working on right now is structured like this:

```
+ public
    - JavaScript
    - styles
+ models
+ views
+ routes
+ services
+ node_modules
```

Comment: Very good answer. Although, I wonder how you include your models. I mean, do you use absolute paths?

Comment: `require('./models/myfile.js');`

Comment: @Ako - I just wrote a short blog post using code from a project I've been working on explaining more: http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1974

Answer (score 0):

Although a subjective answer, I would not consider it bad practise. Indeed, I commonly separate bits of code out into modules in this manner, that I don't want on npm, and aren't really worth putting on a private repo on github. However, it is useful to use them as if they were 'published modules'.